# Client-serv. app run: System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: iis, web, f#, websharper

Have an issue after deploying and running WebSharper client-server app to the remote server: I get `System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.` [Here is a gist with stack trace in my case](https://gist.github.com/ArtemyB/952e02862fd83932c648162e4db69584) . However all is OK on my machine while running with VS 2017 Community (`F# 4.1, WebSharper 3.6.19.242, .NET 4.6`). According to the info specified by hosting provider, their server supports `ASP.NET 4.0, .NET <=4.6.3`.

Still have no idea how to fix that. Can somebody help, please?

**P.S.**: Found very similar question/issue [here](http://websharper.com/question/82284/unaltered-vs-template-throws-typeinitializationexception-exception) (the last comment is mine).

**P.P.S.**: There is no such error with earlier versions of WebSharper, at least `v.3.6.15.238` (`UI.Next v.3.6.15.211`). Tried only this configuration, so don't know from which version exactly the problem appears.